# AVM inside Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, avm

I am trying to put AVMs in a Beamer presentation but it does not seem to work. There is no crash but the AVM has no line breaks. Something as simple as:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{avm}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{avm}
      \[
      FORM \\
      SYN  \\
      SEM
      \]
    \end{avm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Ends up in a single line. AVM works fine with other document classes.

Comment: it would help if you gave a complete example (where is avm defined) but probably you want `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: I've provided a full example. \begin{frame}[fragile] doesn't help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`avm` is an ancient package not included in current distributions. It is incompatible with `array` package (so most latex alignments) and `beamer`

A simple fix in a local copy is to change line 104 so that it looks like

```
%\else \def\\{\@tabularcr}% Leverage off LaTeX's \\*[dimen] options
\else \def\\{\@arraycr}% Leverage off LaTeX's \\*[dimen] options
```

that is, use `\@arraycr` instead of `\@tabularcr`.

Comment: It works. Are there any modern replacements for AVM?

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo I have no idea what it does, you mentioned it without saying where it came from and I found it via google in the historic latex2.09 area on ctan and downloaded it just now.

Comment: I think you have a much older copy of `avm.sty`. The one I have was last changed in 2013 and is (explicitly) compatible with `array`. As far as I can tell, it is also compatible with Beamer.

Comment: @cfr could you add a link?

Comment: See comments on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352874/how-to-center-avms-with-subscripts-in-trees. Direct link: https://www1.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/.