# How to center AVMs with subscripts in trees?

Tags: subscripts, linguistics, tikz-qtree, avm, tensor

I would like to make trees with daughters that are AVMs with subscripts. The subscripts cause the AVMs to slide off to one side. How can I prevent this?

[image: Here the AVM is off-center]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{avm}
\usepackage[]{tensor}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usepackage[]{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.N 
    \node { $\tensor[]{
        \begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}
        {_{}}$};
    \node { $\tensor[]{
        \begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y  \] \end{avm}}
        {_{123}}$}; ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `avm.sty` is to be found where?

Comment: I found it [here.](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/avms/) The documentation is [here.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/avm-doc.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an adapted version of the `avm` style I provided in an answer to your earlier question.

As before the content of each node should be of one of these forms:

- `<regular content>`
- `:<avm spec>`
- `<regular content>:<avm spec>`

In addition,

- `sub left=<subscript>`
- `sub right=<subscript>`

can be used to append subscripts to the left and right of an avm.

To use this, put `avm` in your Forest tree's preamble. The rest should, with a sailing wind and the favour of your local deities, be automatic.

For example,

```
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub right=123
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=1235, sub right=18743
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub right=456
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

will produce the following 4 trees:

[image: trees]

Note that there is an issue here concerning the desiderata. If you increase the distance between siblings, you can keep the branches symmetric in terms of the angles of the branches. However, if you have a large subscript on one side, but not the other, this may end up looking rather strange. It will also increase the width of the tree quite quickly, depending on the size and distribution of subscripts.

If you don't do that, either the edges will not coincide with the tops of the avms (the default position) or the edges at a branch may be at different angles from the tree's direction of growth.

If you keep the subscripts out of the nodes, this isn't a problem. But then you need to either increase the distance between siblings globally or adjust things manually.

This means that the best approach for any tree or set of trees may not be the best for another tree or set of trees.

That is, your kilometres may vary.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{avm,tensor,array}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={sub left}{},
  declare toks={sub right}{},
  declare dimen={sub shift}{0pt},
  Autoforward={sub left}{%
    sub shift+/.pgfmath={.5*(width(#1))},
  },
  Autoforward={sub right}{%
    sub shift+/.pgfmath={-.5*(width(#1))},
  },
  avm/.style={%
    TeX={\setlength\extrarowheight{-10pt}},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        split option={content}{:}{content,make ss avm},
      },
    },
    before packing={%
      for tree={%
        edge path'/.process={Ow{sub shift}{(!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=##1].child anchor)}},
      },
    },
  },
  make ss avm/.style={%
    if content={}{
      content=#1,
      make pure ss avm,
    }{
      content+/.process={%
        OOw2{sub left}{sub right}{%
          \\
          $\tensor[_{##1}]{%
            \begin{avm}#1\end{avm}%
          }{_{##2}}$%
        }%
      },
    },
  },
  make pure ss avm/.style={%
    if={%
      > O_= O_= & {sub right}{}{sub left}{}
    }{%
      content/.wrap value={%
        \begin{avm}##1\end{avm}
      },
    plain content,
    }{
      content/.process={%
        OOOw3{content}{sub left}{sub right}{%
          \tensor[_{##2}]{%
            \begin{avm}##1\end{avm}%
          }{_{##3}}%
        }%
      },
      math content,
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub right=123
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=1235, sub right=18743
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [N
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub right=456
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\], sub left=123
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package. `\mathrlap{123}` will make `123` extend to the right (therefore the `r` in the name of the macro) without occupying space. The downside is that this extension is invisible to any other material around, so you may have to take precautions that there is no overlap.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{avm}
\usepackage[]{tensor}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usepackage[]{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.N 
      {$\tensor[]%
        {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
        {_{}}%
       $%
      }
      {$\tensor[]%
        {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
        {_{\mathrlap{123}}}%
       $%
      }
     ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=5mm]
\Tree[.N 
      {$\tensor[]%
        {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
        {_{\mathrlap{123}}}%
       $%
      }
      {$\tensor[]%
        {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
        {_{\mathrlap{123}}}%
       $%
      }
     ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Another solution using node/child from `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{avm}
\usepackage[]{tensor}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{N}
  child
   {node{$\tensor[]%
          {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
          {_{\mathrlap{123}}}%
         $%
        }
   }
  child 
   {node{$\tensor[]%
          {\begin{avm} \[ X \\ Y \] \end{avm}}%
          {_{\mathrlap{123}}}%
         $%
        }
   };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I put subscripts on the left side, they overlap with the other daughter. What kind of precautions do you mean?

Comment: @J.Bratt You can e.g. adjust the `sibling distance`, see my extended answer.