# Put trees side by side with minipage in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, minipage, forest, linguistics

There are things I don't understand when it comes to the syntax of `minipage`. In the following example (this is my real case and not a MWE), why can't I get a "X or Y" display by having three minipages "X" + "or" + "Y", with `{0.33\linewidth}` for each minipage?

I've tried a dozen or so versions of this (changing the width argument, having two rather than three minipages with an "or" between them, etc.), but I can never get a nice display of this "X or Y" thing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
    \ensuremath{%
        \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
            [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
            [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    or
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [a
            [H]
            [L]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**
This is an example of [autosegmental phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autosegmental_phonology). I'm trying to replicate what is the first illustration of autosegmental phonology in the paper that introduced the theory in the first place (John Goldsmith. 1976. An overview of autosegmental phonology. Linguistic Analysis 2, 23-68):

[image]

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of diagram? I've seen this before ....

Comment: @cfr See edit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution takes an alternative approach. It ditches the `minipage`s and the `\phonfeat`. (If you really want to do it that way, use Forest's `align` option and wrap the node to add the delimiters.)

Instead, I use some styles I wrote to answer questions about the `avm` package. These wrap the `avm` environment in Forest styles.

To achieve the vertical spacing, I modify `begin draw` to use Ti*k*Z's `baseline` option. I then wrap this in `linguistics centre` which sets a default preamble based on the `linguistics` defaults, but without the `baseline` option and with the centring. This means we have `sn edges` etc. active out-of-the box and don't need to set anchors and so on manually.

You can easily apply the `linguistics` and `linguistics centre` defaults in the usual way globally or within a local scope. (I thought you might need the standard defaults for some slides and the centring for others - hence the style rather than a global declaration of a `default preamble`.)

[It would be nice if `linguistics` provided an option to not set `baseline`, since I imagine centring trees vertically is not an uncommon desideratum in Beamer presentations. But perhaps I'm mistaken about this.]

The horizontal spacing is just a couple of `\hfill`s, so that we don't need to worry about the widths of things.

```
% gweler hefyd: ateb: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353744/ addaswy o gwestiwn J. Bratt: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352874/
% gweler hefyd: forest2-1-avm-avm-only.tex forest-2-1-avm-ss-avm.tex, forest2-avm-spacing.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\usepackage{avm,array}
\forestset{%
  avm only/.style={%
    TeX={\setlength\extrarowheight{-10pt}},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        make pure avm,
      },
    },
  },
  make pure avm/.style={%
    content/.wrap value={%
      \begin{avm}##1\end{avm}
    },
    plain content,
  },
  linguistics centre/.style={% based on linguistics defaults: baseline is removed & begin draw is added
    default preamble={
     sn edges,
     for tree={align=center},
     begin draw/.code={\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]},
    },
  },
  linguistics centre,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \hfill
  \begin{forest}
    avm only,
    linguistics centre,
    [\[+syllabic\\$-$high\\+low\\\dots\]
      [\[+highpitch\\$-$lowpitch\]]
      [\[$-$highpitch\\+lowpitch\]]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill
  or\hfill
  \begin{forest}
    linguistics centre,
    [a
      [H]
      [L]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill\hskip0pt%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: centred trees]

If you need sub-scripts etc., see the link mentioned in the code for the `avm` and `make avm` styles which facilitate this.

## EDIT

As I said in the comments, `linguistics centre` is completely independent of `avm only`. The code above uses the former for the second tree and both for the first tree. Hence, the former can be used to manage vertical alignment, without changing anything about the content of the tree.

[image: vertical alignment with Forest]

Both slides use `\phonfeat`: one directly; one indirectly.

As I also mentioned, if you go with `\phonfeat`, note that it introduces a space before the content. If you don't always want a space there, obviously you should remove that space from the macro definition.

[image: spurious space]

The first line uses a definition without the space; the second uses the original definition with it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\newcommand*{\phonfeatorig}[1]{
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\forestset{%
  linguistics centre/.style={% based on linguistics defaults: baseline is removed & begin draw is added
    default preamble={
     sn edges,
     for tree={align=center},
     begin draw/.code={\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]},
    },
  },
  linguistics centre,
  phonfeat/.style={%
    linguistics centre,
    delay={%
      for tree={%
        content/.wrap value=\phonfeat{##1},
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Note the difference:

  \phonfeat{a\\b}\phonfeat{c\\d}

  \phonfeatorig{a\\b}\phonfeatorig{c\\d}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \hfill
  \begin{forest}
    linguistics centre,
    [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\$-$high\\+low\\\dots}
      [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\$-$lowpitch}]
      [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\+lowpitch}]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill
  or\hfill
  \begin{forest}
    linguistics centre,
    [a
      [H]
      [L]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill\hskip0pt%
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \hfill
  \begin{forest}
    phonfeat,
    [+syllabic\\$-$high\\+low\\\dots
      [+highpitch\\$-$lowpitch]
      [$-$highpitch\\+lowpitch]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill
  or\hfill
  \begin{forest}
    linguistics centre,
    [a
      [H]
      [L]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
  \hfill\hskip0pt%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is being done by `avm` and what is being done by `forest` here. I will definitely not use `avm`, since the `\phonfeat` command I use is just one part of a larger `.sty` file I otherwise use for writing [phonological rewrite rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_rule#Example). Also David [says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269941/9077) `avm` is incompatible with both `array` and `beamer`.

Comment: @Sverre Forest is handling the alignment. `avm` is just constructing the node content, so you can use `\phonfeat{}` if you want.

Comment: @Sverre The copy of `avm.sty` I have seems much more recent than the one David found, with the last changes made in 2013. It is compatible with `array` (explicitly) and, as far as I can tell, compatible with Beamer. So I think it is fine to use it unless there are other problems not mentioned in David's answer. However, if `\phonfeat` is already embedded in your stuff, obviously you should just stick with that. You can still use the Forest stuff to get the vertical alignment. I only really used `avm` to demonstrate an alternative, since there were already two answers here.

Comment: @Sverre However, I'd remove the space before the content in the `\phonfeat` definition unless you really do always want it preceded by a space. Here it is going to get trimmed anyway, probably. But if you're using the macro more generally, the extra space will bite you if you aren't careful.

Comment: @Sverre That is, `linguistics centre` is doing the alignments and installing the `linguistics` defaults, *sans* the `baseline` setting. `avm only` is wrapping the content in the `avm` environment. As the second tree shows, you can use the former style without the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm staring at the code, but I'm still confused. Would you mind adding an example that doesn't use all the `avm` stuff? (I'm also curious to see what you mean by the "space before the content in the \phonfeat definition").

Comment: @Sverre See edit above. Really, you just delete all the `avm` stuff and replace your `\phonfeat`, less the space and plus `linguistics centre` :-). But it is always harder to see things with my own code, I find, so no doubt it would be less obvious to me if I'd written the original :(. Please let me know if the edit clears things up.

Answer (score 3):

**Last edit without font change (suggestion):**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
    \ensuremath{%
        \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north, l sep=2em}
        [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
            [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
            [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
    or
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [a
            [H]
            [L]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**First answer (why)**

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
    \ensuremath{%
        \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
            [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
            [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    or
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}}
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [a
            [H]
            [L]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The \fbox shows that your forest is overflowing from the first minipage, so I changed manually the lengths of your minipages.

... `\fbox` solves many questions :P

**Edit (solve with fontsize change):**

But I found something else too:

The below code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
    \ensuremath{%
        \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
            [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
            [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{center}
    or
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [a
            [H]
            [L]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works fine. But if you remove \hfill it gives the last minipage in last row (unless if you reduce any length of the minipage. It is somehow wired. But it is the space between minipages (the token) that causes the problem. So a `%` instead of `\hfill` works fine too.)

Comment: I actually have `%` at the end of every `\end{minipage}` in my actual document, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Sverre Yes, it doesn't fix it if the fontsize in minipage not reduced. I mean for my example that have already reduced the fontsize and it was just wired becase 3*0.33<1.

Comment: (+1) for '`\fbox` can solve many problems. However, the output you show in your diagnostics isn't the output from the original code. It doesn't show the problem. Moreover, you introduce spaces before `minipage`s in some cases, but not others.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to use `\fbox` as a diagnostics here, because if you comment out the `\fbox` lines in your code, you'll see that the distance between the minipages changes. Apparently `\fbox` adds extra whitespace itself.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

widths of your mini pages not follows to width of their content. simpler solution is use `tabular` environment where cell content is encapsulated in `adjustbox` for enabling to determine vertical position of cell's content -- on the top (`valign=t`) or on the middle (`valign=m):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
    \ensuremath{%
        \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \adjustbox{valign=m}{
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
            [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
            [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
        ]
    \end{forest}        }
    &
    \adjustbox{valign=m}{
    or
                        }
    &
    \adjustbox{valign=m}{
    \begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
        [a
            [H]
            [L]
        ]
    \end{forest}        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

in the case, that the align on the bottom is desired, than use of `adjustbox` can be omitted.

**edit:**
`adjustbox` add space around its content (similarly as do `minipage` or `tabular`). if find this disturbing, you can (partly) compensate its horizontal part by setting `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` as is now added to above *mwe*.

i didn't interfere in `forest` tree design. haw it can be improved you can see in nice [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) answer.

Comment: (+1) for a working solution, though it doesn't really appeal to my sense of elegance. (Although it is hard to say just what this consists in, for sure.) I hardly ever use `\adjustbox`, but aren't you adding spaces into the boxes before and after the trees? I know they are being centred, but even so. Or does `\adjustbox` trim its contents of spaces? `\phonfeat` is adding a space, too, I suppose.

Comment: yes, as each box it add space around content, in horisontal direction it can be partly) compensated by reducing `\tabcolsep` to `0pt˙(now added to answer). i didn't interfere in OP design of `forest` tree ... it can be improved, as you shown in your answer :) (+1 for it).

Answer (score 0):

When in Beamer I'm faced with problems like this I always use the *textpos* package with absolute positioning.
After several trial and error, I think that a code that fullfill the requirments of the OP (having three no overlapping boxes of the same width on the same line) could be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos} %absolute positioning
\TPGrid[20mm,20mm]{30}{10}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{
\ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock}{14.54}(0,5)
%\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
    [\phonfeat{+syllabic\\ $-$high\\ +low\\ \dots}
        [\phonfeat{+highpitch\\ $-$lowpitch}]
        [\phonfeat{$-$highpitch\\ +lowpitch}]
    ]
\end{forest}
%\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{14.54}(14.54,5)
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
or
%\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{14.54}(29.08,5)
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{forest} for tree = {parent anchor = south, child anchor = north}
    [a
        [H]
        [L]
    ]
\end{forest}
%\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result seem to me not very pleasant.

[image]